# NVCC src/caffe/layers/elu_layer.cu nvcc fatal : Unknown option 'fPIC' Makefile:607

Tags: caffe

When I make caffe，there is a bug！！！

```
NVCC src/caffe/layers/elu_layer.cu
nvcc fatal   : Unknown option 'fPIC'
Makefile:607: recipe for target '.build_release/cuda/src/caffe/layers/elu_layer.o' failed
make: *** [.build_release/cuda/src/caffe/layers/elu_layer.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

Comment: Please provide information about the operating system, the compiler toolset, and the compilation options you are using. Mentioning the version of caffe you are trying to build might also help.

Comment: I encountered the same error, I resolve it by setting proper CUDA directory to system path and configuring using ccmake.And CUDA_HOST_COMPILER=/usr/bin/cc rather than /usr/local/cuda-10.1/bin/nvcc